# MSSQL - Import Flat File - Incorrect format

Tags: sql-server, csv

I use MSSQL Server 2019, and I would like to insert CSV file into autogenerated DB via:

- **DB -> Tasks -> Import Flat File ...** (got error lower)
- **DB -> Tasks -> Import Data ...** (must export .xlsx to .xls (2003), but not import all rows correctly, row formated like Text with value like 930 or 280 export like null value)

If I select manually all columns as varchar import is ok, but if I use choose float datatype I got an error

DB Collation - ***Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8***

**Data from CSV file:**

```
XXX;XXX;TBJ;A;33;4;1.4;6;3000;1206;3216-18;3.2;0.2;1.6;0.2:0.1;1.8;hre_tbj_dla;K
XXX;XXX;TBJ;A;33;4;1.4;6;3000;1206;3216-18;3.2;0.2;1.6;0.2:0.1;1.8;hre_tbj_dla;M
XXX;XXX;TBJ;A;3.3;6;0.5;6;8000;1206;3216-18;3.2;0.2;1.6;0.2:0.1;1.8;hre_tbj_dla;K
```

**Data loaded into MSSQL Import Flat Data Wizard:**
[image]

[image]

[image]

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Error inserting data into table. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Import.Wizard)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error inserting data into table. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import)

------------------------------

The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type float of the specified target column. (System.Data)

------------------------------

Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Double. (System.Data)

------------------------------

Input string was not in a correct format. (mscorlib)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Comment: Try importing just 1 line of data. Does that work? If that does not work change all the mappings back to `nvarchar` and then change one column at a time and import. Do this until you find the offending column mapping and then hopefully it should/might become more evident why that value cannot be converted to the desired type.

Comment: ↑ (continued) If the first row does work with the mappings then there is an unexpected value in one of the rows and it is up to you to figure out what row contains the anomaly. It could be that there is a missing/extra `;` delaminator or that a value is simply incorrect.

Comment: Hiding the column names, and then not giving us an easy way to tell what column maps to what in the images doesn't make thuis easy for us. I'm not sure what you're expecting to really "hide" here either by not giving us column names.

Comment: I try this, but for each number type column I got this error (other columns I set to NVARCHAR), the delimiter is ; and is ok (also Import Wizard show data correctly), I use this file in-app and it is ok, and also If I try to upload this file to Oracle DB everything is OK

Comment: Try to open that flat file on LibCalc or Excel and Save/Export loaded data to CSV. After that try to load that output CSV file.

Comment: I try it also, but with same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try a different type of load data via **BULK INSERT**

1. Create an empty table with rows
2. use BULK INSERT

**Example:**

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[xxx]
    FROM 'c:\Users\xxx\Documents\Work\xxx.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'c:\Users\xxx\Documents\Work\xxx_error.csv',
    TABLOCK
    );
```

Everything work perfectly

Comment: table with  type float of the specified target column? using TABLOCK ?

Comment: I use TABLOCK for LOCK table data by import. For float value in excel/csv use DB float data type, simply check columns in csv and by that create by data type same table in DB

Comment: `c:\Users\xxx\` path in MSSQL server ?

Comment: Yes, no problem with this, use this path to call csv file in Windows use MSSQL 2019